# How to get more info about a specific attribute?

Tags: maya

I guess this is a stupid question, so I apologize in advance but I couldn't find the answer anywhere and I guess I didn't even really know how to search for an answer.

How do I find out more about an attribute (not even sure if that's the right word)? For example, if I do:

```
listAttr bifrostShape1
```

then I get a long list of ... attributes? .. one of them is called "particleChannel". I want to know more about "particleChannel" so I tried:

```
listAttr "bifrostShape1.particleChannel"
```

got nothing basically - returned: "particleChannel" , so I tried:

```
getAttr "bifrostShape1.particleChannel"
```

and I got result: "position"...
this is actually what I think I'm looking for and I want to know more about this, what is this "position"?

searching for "particleChannel" in the reference and online gave me nothing, and trying "listAttr and getAttr of "bifrostShape1.particleChannel.position" gave me an error..

What I'm actually trying to achieve is to get attributes of the particles in a bifrost liquid... but my question is actually: How do I find out more about something when I stumble over it like this? What is the way to find out more about a command or attribute?
This is my favorite way to learn so I really hope that there's a good way to do it in maya.

Comment: Usually you would need to check out its documentation to get more details on what it is and how to use it. You can also use `dir()`, `help()`, and `type()` on it to try and get more info.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [attributeQuery](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/attributeQuery.html)

You can do a lot of queries about an attribute, see docs in the link.